# jquery HTML5 details and summary, problems counting children

Tags: jquery, children, html-tag-details, html-tag-summary

I'm having problems counting children in a huge 'index-like' file which uses the details and summary tags. Need to know how many children there are for a specific summary tag. The code example has just a small part of the complete file but it shows what I'm looking for: I call the function getAnswer with a 'href' value, the function does find the correct entry but from there I'm stuck: How to find the number of children.
The commented-out lines show that I tried various things, but they all give the answer 0, so I guess I cannot use $(this).
Any help is appreciated !!

```js
getAnswer('2013'); // should be 4
getAnswer('2013_spring'); // should be 0
getAnswer('2013_summer'); // should be 0
getAnswer('2013_autumn'); // should be 3

function getAnswer(question) {
  var numChilds = $('summary a[href="' + question + '"]').length; // 1001
  if (numChilds == 1) { // then a summary record was found
    console.log('Found summary for ' + question);
    // console.log('Nr of children for ' + question + ': ' + $(this).parent("details").children().length);  
    // console.log('Nr of children for ' + question + ': ' + $(this).parent("ul").children().length); 
    // console.log('Nr of children for ' + question + ': ' + $(this).parent("details > li").length); 
    // console.log('Nr of children for ' + question + ': ' + $(this).next("ul li").length); 
    // console.log('Nr of children for ' + question + ': ' + $(this).next("ul > li").length); 
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <details>
    <summary><a class="sitemap" href="2013">Year</a></summary>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="sitemap" href="2013_spring">Spring</a></li>
      <li><a class="sitemap" href="2013_summer">Summer</a></li>
      <ul>
        <details>
          <summary><a class="sitemap" href="2013_autumn">Autumn</a></summary>
          <ul>
            <li><a class="sitemap" href="apples">Delicious Apples</a></li>
            <li><a class="sitemap" href="bananas">Yellow Bananas</a></li>
            <li><a class="sitemap" href="cacao">Warm Chocolate</a></li>
          </ul>
        </details>
      </ul>
      <li><a class="sitemap" href="2013_winter">Winter</a></li>
    </ul>
  </details>
</ul>
```

Comment: You want to find the number of `a` children?

Comment: `$('summary a[href="' + question + '"]').each(function() { here you can use $(this) });`

Comment: To Mojo Allmighty: yes, if there is a hit, e.g. 2013_autumn, I need to know how many children there are for this summary, so answer should be 3, because there are 3 <li> tags in the <ul> under this found summary.

Comment: To mplungjan: Thanks, totally forgot to have the $(this) inside a function that found a hit. ThankU !

Answer (score 0):

After mplungjan refreshed my memory of how to use $(this), I came to the conclusion that there must be a better and faster way, so after a while I came up with the following solution to find the number of children, 'belonging to' **summary**:

```
var numChilds = $('summary a[href="' + question + '"]').parent().next().children().length;
```

Getting the number of children ‘belonging to’ **summary** is not as straight forward as it should be, because summary as such ‘stands alone’, therefore it doesn’t have children; the children belong to the **ul** which is also (as summary is as well) part of **details**.

what does the above code do:
It finds the summary ‘record’ with the unique href value, then it finds its **parent**, which is SUMMARY, you can check with this code:

```
$('summary a[href="' + question + '"]').parent()[0].nodeName;
```

It then finds the **next** sibling of **summary**, which is **ul** (they both are children of **details**, therefore **next** can be used). For this **ul** it then asks for the **number** (.length) of **children**.
So by going back one step, and then two forwards, you get the number of children.

Hope this is/was useful for somebody. At least it was for me.